# What is the difference between copulas and normalizing flows?

Tags: copula, normalizing-flow

The goal of normalizing flows is to produce arbitrarily complex probability-distributions from a simple distribution (usually the Normal distribution) through learning an invertible transform.

Copulas model a joint distribution by transforming marginals into standard uniform distributions and learning/finding the dependence structure (copula) between them

Can someone clarify what are actually the differences between these two approaches? I don't understand why normalizing flows is needed, when Sklar's theorem states that any joint distribution can be described using the copula-approach. Is it simply because finding the copula is hard and normalizing flows gives us a neat way to learn it?

Comment: Normalizing flows provide direct estimates and can capture complex dependencies, while copula can only capture dependencies, including complex ones, but cannot provide a direct estimate.

Comment: By direct estimates you mean that the output of normalizing flows is a distribution in $R^n$, while the output of a copula lies in the unit hypersphere?

Comment: Yes. You can use the NFs to estimate the PDF directly, while the copula needs an estimator to do this step. I found this paper that may help you. https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.07352

Comment: The words "copula" and "normalising flows" describe two different categories of things. A copula is just a multivariate distribution with uniform margins. Sklar's theorem tells you that margins and copula together are essentially the same as multivariate distributions. In that sense a copula does not "learn/find" a dependency structure but it IS one. NFs are one way (among many others) to create multivariate distributions hence also to create (or learn or estimate) copulas.